# Angular Karma E2E Testing to external link

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to test a link to go to a twitter page. Is this possible?

index.html

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://twitter.com/foo">@foo</a>
```

karma-e2e.conf.js

```
proxies : {
  '/': 'http://localhost:8000/',
  '/twitter/': 'https://twitter.com/'
},
```

scenarios.js

```
it('should redirect to twitter page when link is clicked', function() {
  element('.navbar a').click();
  expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/twitter/foo');
});
```

Error

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9877" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at /foobar/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js:43
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've set on it to work for e2e tester:

```
 config.set({
            browsers: ['chrome_without_security'],
            customLaunchers: {
                chrome_without_security: {
                    base: 'Chrome',
                    flags: ['--disable-web-security']
                }
            }
        });
```